# Find the number of unique paths, given a fixed set, that produce a given output.

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I'm looking to find the probability of selecting a given number M given a set of N numbers in a bounded range (or potentially in several differently bounded ranges, but I'm starting simple). I'm trying to come up with the probability of a number of dice rolls, so as an example, given that I roll 3 six-sided die, what is the probability of a 10? Or, given five 20-sided die, what is the probability of a 64?

I know that in the case of the 3 six-sided die, the chance of an 18 or a 3 are both (1/6)^3, or 1/216, because only a single combination of values can produce either 3 or 18. But what about a number like 10? It has multiple combinations that can produce it, like 3+3+4, or 6+2+2. I know that there are 216 unique paths available given the three six-sided die, and that the end probability of rolling any number M will then be the number of unique paths that produce a number times 1/216, which should work even given a number outside the summable range (Since the number of unique paths that could equal that number would be 0).

So I guess my question really boils down to: how can I determine the number of unique paths or combinations that will sum to any given number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want $N$ dice with $s$ sides each to add up to $M$. This corresponds to distributing $M$ balls into $N$ non-empty bins with capacity $s$, or equivalently distributing $M-N$ balls into (possibly empty) bins with capacity $s-1$. The number of ways of doing this can be calculated using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), and the result is given at [Balls In Bins With Limited Capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm) (which also covers the case of different capacities that you're potentially interested in). For the above dice throw, the result is

$$
\sum_{t=0}^N(-1)^t\binom Nt\binom{M-st-1}{N-1}\;,
$$

where, contrary to convention, the binomial coefficient is taken to be $0$ if the upper index is negative. This needs to be divided by $s^N$, the total number of possible throws.

In your first example, $N=3$, $s=6$ and $M=10$, which gives the probability

\begin{align}
&\frac1{6^3}\sum_{t=0}^3(-1)^t\binom 3t\binom{10-6t-1}{3-1}\\
={}&\frac{\binom92-3\binom32}{6^3}\\
={}&\frac{36-9}{6^3}&\\
={}&\frac18\;.
\end{align}

In your second example, $N=5$, $s=20$ and $M=64$, which gives the probability

\begin{align}
&\frac1{20^5}\sum_{t=0}^5(-1)^t\binom 5t\binom{64-20t-1}{5-1}\\
={}&\frac{\binom{63}4-5\binom{43}4+10\binom{23}4}{20^5}\\
={}&\frac{595665-617050+88550}{20^5}\\
={}&\frac{67165}{20^5}\\
={}&\frac{13433}{640000}\\
\approx{}&0.021\;.
\end{align}